# How to derive the time dilation in special relativity when the velocity is in arbitrary direction?

Tags: special-relativity

We know that the v in the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ stands for the speed of the frame S' when it comes to time dilation. But for the derivation, I can only see proof when S and S' are in standard configuration. How do we derive time dilation when the velocity of S' is in an arbitrary direction relative to S?

Comment: How is the standard configuration not arbitrary?

Comment: Because S' only moves in the x direction

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to derive it directly from the metric:

$$d\tau^2=-ds^2/c^2=dt^2-dx^2/c^2-dy^2/c^2-dz^2/c^2$$ $$ \frac{d\tau^2}{dt^2}=1-\frac{1}{c^2}\left( \frac{dx^2}{dt^2}+\frac{dy^2}{dt^2}+\frac{dz^2}{dt^2} \right) $$ $$\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{1}{\gamma}=\sqrt{ 1-v^2/c^2  }$$

So the end result is that the direction doesn’t matter.

Comment: But we developed the metric assuming $cd\tau = \frac{cdt}{\gamma}$where v in $\gamma$ is the speed.

Comment: There are many ways to develop the metric.